# how to load 2 cppflow models in memory and make inference with auto prediction = (*model)(input)

Tags: c++, cppflow

I would like to know how to load two models in memory and make inference with model1 or model2 like I want?

```
int __stdcall BinaCpp_loadNN(const char* filename)
{
    //loading the model each time causes overload. 
    //The other option is to create a unique pointer which will be loaded once when first called.

    //Declare unique pointer:

    std::unique_ptr<cppflow::model> model;

    model = std::make_unique<cppflow::model>(filename);

    return model;  //issue here
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. Specifically why is the function declared to return an `int` where you attempt to return a `unique_ptr`.

Comment: //Then use the model to make predictions:

auto prediction = (*model)(input)

Comment: Please add much more detail and also read [mre].

Comment: @JesperJuhl  I try to use this code : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67581111/loading-tensorflow-model-to-manipulate-an-audio-stream-with-c)